# Why doesn't Metal have a rgb8Unorm MTLPixelFormat?

Tags: ios, metal

I have a number of textures which don't require an alpha channel. Currently, I'm loading these using the `MTLPixelFormat` `rgba8Unorm` option, but this seems somewhat wasteful. Is there an option I'm missing, or some other rationale behind omitting a format with 3 8-bit components for texture data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is answerable because it would require knowing the intent of people at Apple, and we can't know that for sure. We can only guess.

One such guess is that they only support pixel formats that have direct hardware support on common GPUs. Note that a) part of Metal's design philosophy is to eliminate implicit work by the API and driver, which would include format conversions. Such work is left for the application code itself to do. And b) not all formats that they do support somewhere are supported everywhere. For example, why isn't `BGR5A1Unorm` supported on macOS? It's surely convertible to `BGRA8Unorm` but they don't.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably because rgb8 uses 24 bits, which is not a nice power of 2, and computers like to use powers of 2, especially for addressing data.

Comment: This is the correct answer, each pixel is represented as BGRA (32 bits) and in the case of no alpha the alpha channel is just 0xFF at all times. There is a space savings possible when writing image data to a file as 24 BPP, but when sitting in memory, the pixels are always going to be 32 bits each.